# requesting artist biography is missing in spotify api docs

Tags: spotify

I've looked everywhere in the Spotify API documentation as well as spending an hour or so circumventing plan A, by trying to use Rovi's API (Spotify's data provider, I think...). Rovi's music api access is a mess, btw.

Anybody have success in retrieving an artist's biography text data? (see ex image)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Artist's biography it's just not added in any endpoint of the Spotify's API. If you see the biography in Spotify app that's probably because the app uses a closed API whose documentation it's not available to the public.

Comment: Thanks. I had a feeling that was the case. I've noticed a lot of those bio's are signed by the writer/editor all of whom have Rovi appended to their signature. Apparently Rovi had a public developer facing API at one time, but it now appears to have been abandoned.

Comment: Rovi was purchased by TiVo so right now they are integrating boths APIs into one.